# Hiding api key with firebase function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, function, api, key

I'm trying to hide my `reCAPTCHA` key from appearing in my front end (React). I don't know how useful it can be but how about making a request to a certain endpoint and then make it a `componentDidMount` when getting the data back. This might sound not secure at all but what's the best solution for these kinds of problems?

---

ok so I should create a function (that I still don't get right) that looks similar to this

```
exports.captcha = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => { 
//should i set the origin to be my domain.com here  
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS');   res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');  
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
 res.end(); 
}  else {  
 cors(req, res, () => {
  if (req.method !== 'GET') { 
   return; 
 } 
   return res.send('Api key',(err,info)=> {
    if(err){
     return res.send(err.toString())
    }
      return res.send("sent")
    }  
 });  
}});
```

Comment: I think you can move recaptcha logic to firebase if you don't want to expose your key, create a cloud function, and send a request to that. Not sure if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time the API key is used inside client-side code, a malicious user can take it and use it. Since that is exactly what you're trying to prevent, the only secure solution is to not use that API key in client-side code. That means you'll need to wrap the functionality in your server-side code, and expose only inputs and outputs that you want. It also means you'll want to secure access to the Cloud Functions endpoint (who can call it and what they can do), as unsecured access is equivalent to allowing them to use the API key directly.

Some API keys, such as those for Firebase's Authentication, Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore, and Cloud Storage products allow you to restrict where or how a user with the keys can use those products. In cases such as those, it's better to see the API keys as configuration data

Comment: there must be some typo already, i't similar to another function that i had set up before perhaps do i need to specify the origin to be from "say my domain.com"

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your input, regarding hiding third party API keys how does Firebase step in?, I currently use Firebase Realtime Database, Authentication, Storage and Cloud functions, but i haven't found any tutorials on how to hide third party API keys.

Comment: You shouldn't use such API keys in client-side code. There's not much to step in beyond that. If you're wondering how to run server-side code on Firebase, have a look at Cloud Functions.